# CollectionView issue - Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I make music player using collectionView. I want to when selected collectionView like radio button. If another cell is selected, the selected cell should not be selected. but is not working.

[I dont want multi selection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATj3J.png) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATj3J.png

How do I work? TT I need your help. thx.

this my code.

```
       import UIKit

class PracticeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


var homeClassInPrac = HomeViewController()
var songPlayOff = UIImage(named: "play")
var songPlayOn = UIImage(named: "iconStop")
var buttonCounter = [Int]()
var freqNameList = ["Delta 1","Theta 1","Alpha 1","Beta 1","Delta 2","Theta 2","Alpha 2","Beta 2","Delta 3","Theta 3","Alpha 3","Beta 3","Delta 4","Theta 4","Alpha 4","Beta 4"]


@IBOutlet var practiceCollection: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    practiceCollection.delegate = self
    practiceCollection.dataSource = self
    self.practiceCollection.allowsMultipleSelection = false

}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    self.practiceCollection.reloadData()
    return freqNameList.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:PracticeCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "pracCell", for: indexPath) as! PracticeCollectionViewCell

    cell.pracImgView.image = songPlayOff
    cell.pracLabel.text = freqNameList[indexPath.row]
    if buttonCounter.contains(indexPath.row){
        cell.pracImgView.image = songPlayOn
    }
    else{
        cell.pracImgView.image = songPlayOff
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        if buttonCounter.contains(indexPath.row){
            let index = buttonCounter.index(of: indexPath.row)
            buttonCounter.remove(at: index!)
            self.practiceCollection.reloadData()
            homeClassInPrac.audioPlayer2.stop()
        }
        else{
            buttonCounter.removeAll()
            buttonCounter.append(indexPath.row)
            self.practiceCollection.reloadData()
            let buttonInt = buttonCounter[0]
            homeClassInPrac.playSound2(freqName: freqNameList[buttonInt])
    }
print("Select\(buttonCounter)")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Deselect\(buttonCounter)")
        let index = buttonCounter.index(of: indexPath.row)
        buttonCounter.remove(at: index!)
        self.practiceCollection.reloadData()
        print("Deselect\(buttonCounter)")

}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false in your code?

Comment: yes. already have. self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false in viewDidLoad.

Comment: add this function in your code override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                print("Deselect")
        }
 and check whether it is being called when you select another item?

Comment: oh, not worked! func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { print("Deselect") }. it mean I'll fix didSelectItemAt code?

Comment: Is your didSelectItemAt method is being called correctly?

Comment: It seems that a code `collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` can not be executed `didDeselectItemAt `.

Comment: try self.collectionView.reloadData() instead of collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath]) and see what is the behaviour

Comment: it work same. It doesn't change didDeselectItem cell image.

Comment: didDeselectItem method is called?

Comment: Can you show the code for PracticeCollectionViewCell ?

Comment: please show the PracticeCollectionViewCell (Cell) in your question and please remove the code from answer, I added it in your question

Comment: Please remove this line from numberOfItemsInSection method self.practiceCollection.reloadData() and please show code for PracticeCollectionViewCell

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to use stakoverflow question. so here is my PracticeCollectionViewCell code. `import UIKit

class PracticeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var pracImgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var pracLabel: UILabel!
    
    
}`

Comment: have you removed self.practiceCollection.reloadData()  from numberOfItemsInSection  ?

Comment: yes, I removed.

Comment: It working! but when I click the first time, cell image doesn't change.

Comment: Ok if you change the reloadData in didSelectItemAt method to reloadItems , that you were doing initially , then what is the result?

Comment: It works perfectly now!!!!

Comment: Good work , you got it

Comment: I think your problem was you were reloading data in numberOfItems method, so I have added it as answer, please accept it if it helps you, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is  you are reloading collectionView in `numberOfItems` method

so Just remove

```
 self.practiceCollection.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change buttonCounter to Array of Bool with equal count to freqNameList

```
var buttonCounter : Array<Bool> = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
```

In cellForItem method use :

```
if buttonCounter[indexPath.row]{
        cell.pracImgView.image = songPlayOn
    }
    else{
        cell.pracImgView.image = songPlayOff
    }
```

In didSelectItem use :

```
buttonCounter[indexPath.row] = true
homeClassInPrac.playSound2(freqName: freqNameList[buttonInt])
self.practiceCollection.reloadData()
```

In didDeselectItem use :

```
buttonCounter[indexPath.row] = false
self.practiceCollection.reloadData()
```